# How to set custom frame to iOS Salesforce Login Screen(UIWebView)?

Tags: community, oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I'm showing Salesforce login screen in my iOS native application, but their login screen (WebView) is covering my entire custom screen and I'm not able to show the status bar and navigation bar at top side. I have written code in `willDisplayAuthWebView` method as mentioned below

```
- (void)authManager:(SFAuthenticationManager *)manager willDisplayAuthWebView:(UIWebView *)view{

    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y += 64;
    view.frame = newFrame;
    [Self.View addSubview:view];
}
```

[image]

but no luck. Is there anyway to handle this issue. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this sample app](https://github.com/khawkins/Sandbox/tree/master/AuthInPopover) that I created, to demonstrate launching the authentication view in a `UIPopoverController`.  It should hopefully provide the basics for how you can generally customize your login view experience in your native app.