# Create custom Salesforce Login Page in iOS/Android while using the SDK

Tags: login, salesforce-sdk-android, salesforce-sdk-hybrid, salesforcesdk

Currently when we use the salesforce SDK it opens up a default page from

https://test.salesforce.com

or

https://login.salesforce.com

The design of these two pages is of salesforce default login page.

I want to create a custom login page in my application so that instead of loading the web-view from SDK my app open ups my custom login page and I use the SDK authentication classes to authorise the user.

Is there any possibility to use Login API with salesforce SDK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom frame to iOS Salesforce Login Screen(UIWebView)?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60811/how-to-set-custom-frame-to-ios-salesforce-login-screenuiwebview)